# How to install Windows with no CD drive boot option in BIOS?

Tags: windows-vista, bios, computer-building, efi

I have a new computer which I built from scratch and I am trying to install a copy of Windows Vista on it. I am able to get to the BIOS and change the boot options which are as follows..

-Built-in EFI Shell
-SATA: ST31000528AS

I have searched around for and everything I find says to boot from the CD rom. However, as you can see. That is not an option for me.

So I am wondering if there is another way around this? Is it possible to boot the Disk from the EFI Shell?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT:**

I have tried this..
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744321%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

**UPDATE:**

I managed to make my USB bootable via the BIOS and I have copied my windows Vista disk onto my USB via drag and drop. However I am still not able to get the windows install to start. Also I have tried booting it from the EFI shell using the following command..

```
blk6:
blk6:\> \EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI
```

Still no luck..

**SOLVED:**

I wasn't ever able to boot using a DVD. So I ended up downloading a Windows 7 ISO and creating a bootable USB using this: http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool

Suggested by Karan... Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: Can you not boot from the USB? If you can then its the fastest way to install  the Windows.

Comment: @avirk Yes I can.. I just copied my windows Vista Disk to a USB drive. I am booting using the USB, but no luck yet.. Still just a blinking cursor..

Comment: Which tool you have used to make it bootable?

Comment: I just dragged the files on to the USB stick. And then switch the boot order in the BIOS. Also I tried to boot if using EFI

Comment: No you have to use the tool to make it bootable like [WintoFlash](http://wintoflash.com/download/en/) or [yumi](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/). Just drag and drop will not make USB bootable. Also set the USB on the highest priority in the boot menu from the BIOS settings.

Comment: Okay I will give that a try...

Comment: @avirk How can I make my Vista CD into an ISO?

Comment: Never mind.. I found something called Magic Iso Maker.. Going to give that a shot.. http://www.magiciso.com/

Comment: WintoFlash doesn't need an ISO for make USB bootable but YUMI needs.

Comment: You can try [ISO maker](http://www.softpedia.com/get/CD-DVD-Tools/CD-DVD-Images-Utils/Achal-Jain-ISO-Maker.shtml) which is freeware.

Comment: I wasn't able to get it to work using Yumi and Vista. However I did manage to create a windows 7 bootable device with a windows 7 ISO and  the MS utility suggested by Karan. Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This TechNet article should help: [Installing Windows to an EFI-Based Computer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744321%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: I have tried that with no luck.. I will post my error

Comment: When trying that I get this error .. '\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file

Comment: Did you switch to the DVD drive first? As mentioned in the article, you need to first switch to `Fs0:` or whatever your DVD drive is, then issue the `\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI` command. If you don't know your DVD drive, try the `map` command and check the output - it should display the **device mapping table**. Also, have you tried booting via USB? Does inserting a USB drive and then entering the BIOS add to the boot options list?

Comment: I haven't tried USB. I am trying to use a Windows Vista CD.. I am assuming the disk drive doesn't show up as an option because there are no drivers installed.. Or is that a false assumption?

Comment: Ok, try the `map` command first and see what it has to say.

Comment: Okay.. I got a device mapping table ... fs0 : HardDisk ... and some more info

Comment: Right, so which device name is for the DVD drive?

Comment: I don't see a DVD drive in the list... I see 6 options for :HardDisk and one option for :BlockDevice

Comment: Make sure you have the DVD inserted in the drive, then use `map`. Beyond this, I'm out of ideas ATM.

Comment: Yeah I have it inserted.. I am wondering if my disc drive is faulty. It is a used disc drive that I took out of an older PC..

Comment: Well thanks anyways for all of your help..I really appreciate it.

Comment: NP, I read elsewhere that someone with a similar issue solved it using a USB setup (for which [this MS utility](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool) should help). Also, you should probably edit your question to include the motherboard model and any other relevant details.

Comment: Okay thanks for the info.. My first time using Super User so I wasn't really sure what type of info to include.

Comment: I am trying to do this with USB now but I most be doing something wrong.. I can see my USB in the map list so I know I am getting close..

Comment: @Karan just giving the link on SU is not warm welcomed, so you should have to include the important info in your post and give the link for reference.

Comment: The MS utility ended up being the answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Kris: Glad you got it installed finally. BTW, I have used the MS utility only for Win7 so far, but it is supposed to work equally well for Vista and Win8 too. If you have only the DVD and want to transfer it to USB, you can either create an ISO first using something like [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com) and then use the MS utility, or you can follow the manual creation steps outlined in [this tutorial](http://arstechnica.com/business/2009/12/the-usb-flash-drive/2/) (at the end where they tell you to copy the files to the USB from the ISO, you'll obviously copy from the DVD instead).